# Placing google analyics in footer

Tags: google-analytics

Which is the best place to put google analytics, the header or footer. Can I put it before the  tag or can it be along with the scripts before the closing body tag

Answer (score 1):

both the [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) version and [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) version officially state to put it just before the closing `</head>` tag.  But just between you, me and the fence post, there is no significant difference regardless of where you put it. Some people like putting the whole thing in the head tag. Some people like putting it in the footer. Some people like splitting the code up so that they can more easily have custom code sandwiched inbetween (I personally like this style the best).  Each school of thought will claim it's the bestest and other methods are stupidest. The war rages on.

Comment: I am working on a system already built before, and I have not found out where the pages start but found out the end tag template. I assume google will definitely track the pages regardless of where the code is placed.

Comment: @user3418540 GA will definitely track regardless of where you put it. It's just the nuances and caveats about it that make people favor one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it that way: You implement GA in the footer and a problem occurs. Then you go to a help site and say "I have a problem with my code and btw. I did not implement it according to Googles documentation because I did not feel it was necessary". At that point most people will tell you to fix your code and report back later.

So in the worst case you do not loose anything by doing it right, in the best case you have skipped one annoying step with trouble shooting. Sounds like a no-brainer to me.

To address Crayons argument that it is not necessary to identify partially loading sites (see discussion in the comments to his answer): These will be most likely sites where users exit the page due to the errors, so you want to have them in your tracking (since this will show you where your site needs fixing).  Unless all you want is a page counter in which case GA is a bit overfeatured anyway.

(Btw. this is an answer to your question "which is the *best* place". Should you have meant "Will Google Analytics still track most things if I implement it any-old-where" then the answer is "yes", as Crayon has pointed out).